# jquery addClass in a Rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a JQuery function in a Rails application to add a class attribute `active` to an element on click, I think what is happening is that since when a user clicks the link I do a full page reload and the class attribute is not being added permanently.  Is there a way to add the class based on the route I'm in or the URL?

```
$(document).on('click', '#pg-plans', function(e){
  $("#pg-plans").addClass('active');
});
```

My link is:

```
<li><%= link_to "Plans", company_company_plan_path(current_company, current_company.get_plan), :data_company => current_company.id, :id => "pg-plans" %></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "added permanently"? Right now you're not stopping the default event handling, so the page will reload. If you want something to happen on the back end on a click then you'd need to make the link a remote link. If you don't, then stop the default event handling.

Comment: I want to keep the class of active when the page reloads, I guess I have to do the prevent-default.  Is there anyway to access the current route I am in the js?  Then I could do a conditional.

Comment: not entirely clear on what you are trying to do - does the link have to trigger some sort of action that you are trying to AJAX? Or is it just there to turn "active" upon click? If so, you can just add a `e.preventDefault()` before your addClass code

Comment: from what I understood he wants to show in the UI what page user is currently viewing, that way if you add before refresh obviously it won't keep, you need to check which page you're in after refresh(in other words when you access some page) and then add the class active

Comment: If you want to "persist the class" then when you *load* the page you need to set the element's class(es) based on data that you've persisted on the server side.

Comment: I want to add a highlight to the tab that the user viewing, I solved my problem using current_page?, with a conditional.